# Getting incompatible jackson version while reading a file in spark scala

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, jackson

I am trying to read a simple json file using spark scala using below code

```
val data =spark.read.option("multiLine",true).json(jsonpath)
```

However I am getting error while reading it

**Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Incompatible Jackson version: 2.11.2**

Here is the sbt file

```
 "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.4.0",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.4.0",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "2.4.0",
  "com.fasterxml.jackson.module" %% "jackson-module-scala" % "2.6.7.1",
  "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-databind" % "2.6.7",
  "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-core" % "2.6.7"
```

I have tried with different version. I am not able to find the compatible version for spark 2.4

Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Spark comes with its own version of Jackson. And Jackson is not compatible between minor releases. Thus you cannot have a mix of Jackson version dependencies in your project.

The easiest way to avoid trouble is to use the same version as Spark and mark the dependency as `Provided` in your build definition.

For Spark 2.4.x, it's Jackson 2.6.x to be used. See for instance on https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core_2.12/2.4.8

EDIT: you should also make sure that you don't have another dependency that pulls another Jackson version. You can use SBT `dependencyOverrides` to achieve this.

---

Note that there's also the possibility to include another version of Jackson and force Spark to use it by using the "userClasspathFirst" property. I'll let the reader find information about this if needed.